# Creating a git repo from an existing project, and running `git diff`

Tags: git

I have an (outdated) copy of a git repository, without any git tracking. (no `.git` folder at all)

I want to see how different it is from the original git repository, without affecting the remote git repository.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
git init
git remote add origin {origin_URL}
git fetch --all
git --no-pager diff -R origin/master --numstat
```

... but this just lists ALL the files, and says that none of them exist locally.

Maybe this is because I haven't added any files to git tracking locally?

Would I have to make a new local branch, commit changes to it, and then compare that to the origin/master branch (and then delete the branch, because I don't need it)? Or is there a way to do it without creating a branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add the whole project to the staging area (tracking), view the changes comparing to your remote repository, and then unstage the added files.

```
git init
git remote add origin {origin_URL}
git fetch --all
# stage files
git add .
git --no-pager diff -R origin/master --numstat
# unstage them
git reset
```