# Git - add all local files that are tracked remotely

Tags: git

I have an (outdated) copy of a git repository, without any git tracking. (no .git folder at all)

I want to initialize `git`, connect it to the remote repository, and temporarily add the files in the local copy so I can compare them to the files in the remote.

However, I *don't* want to compare files that don't exist in the remote environment.

Thanks to the answer I got to [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53774738/creating-a-git-repo-from-an-existing-project-and-running-git-diff), this is what I've got so far:

```
git init
git remote add origin {origin_URL}
git fetch --all
# stage files
git add .
git --no-pager diff -R origin/master --numstat
# unstage them
git reset
```

However, the out-of-date local copy of the repo has tons of "extra" files (that I don't care about), making it difficult to see just what files have changed.

Is there a way to add *only* files that are tracked remotely, (ignoring files that only exist locally) without adding all the files / directories that I want to ignore to `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [the manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff):

```
git --no-pager diff -R origin/master --numstat --diff-filter=d
```

the `--diff-filter=d` excludes files that were "deleted". Since I'm doing the diff in reverse in this case, that means files that exist locally but not remotely. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It's worth noting (for clarity of thought in the future) that this isn't files that are *tracked remotely*, it's *files that are in the `origin/master` commit, but not in the work-tree*. The idea of a *tracked file* in Git is that it is a file that is in your index (right now, regardless of what's in any commit anywhere at any time). That's irrelevant here since you are comparing a commit to your work-tree, ignoring your index.